# В NodeJS не удается перейти на папку вверх для выполнения команды

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, webpack

Для запуска WebPack (который в родительской папке) использую Gulp, по как только в пути пытаюсь перейти к родительской папке, то получаю ошибку.

Gulp

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('_Scada2', function (done) {
  spawn('webpack', [], { cwd: '../../Scada.Web/' })
    .on('close', done);
});
```

Получаю ошибку

```
[14:20:47] '_Scada2' errored after 4.47 ms
[14:20:47] Error: spawn webpack ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Процесс завершен с кодом 1.
```

Comment: А webpack у вас только в PATH лежит?

Comment: Он установлен глобально, поэтому думаю, что можно так вызывать. Когда устанавливаю Gulp в туже папку где и Webpack, то он идеально запускается

Answer (score 0):

`ENOENT` появляется, когда не получается найти исполнительный файл для запуска. В этом случае вам нужно использовать либо `npx webpack`, либо использовать официальный способ из документации https://webpack.js.org/guides/integrations/#gulp

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack({
      // Any configuration options...
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```